# how to fix not having filter mode in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine, pixel, game-development

Hello so basically I want to fix my pixel art in unity and what i have found is that i should change the filter mode to point but the thing is I don't seem to have filter mode ( I'm new to Unity ) if u can help would be amazing ;-;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To properly setup your pixelart assets in Unity, you should change some default settings in the import asset phase.

In your project window, click the Texture you just imported and look at the Inspector Panel.

You need to change these two settings:

- **Filter Mode** to **Point (no filter)**
- **Compression** to **None**

[image: Unity Inspector Texture Import Settings]

You can also consider to change **Pixel Per Unit** setting, which basically is, as the tooltip says, how many pixels in the sprite correspond to one unit in the world.

This setting can help you to easily understand the correspondence between the dimensions of your texture/sprite and the units of Unity (it's an habit to consider 1 Unity Unit = 1 meter).

Of course, if you do this, you should chose a standard Pixel Per Unit value and   use it in every texture/sprite you import.

Answer (score 0):

This is found in the `Texture Inspector`.

Click on your texture asset in the project window.

[image: Project Window]

In the inspector you should see all the options for your texture.

[image: FilterMode in Texture Inspector]

You can also do this from code

```
public Texture myTexture;
...
myTexture.filterMode = FilterMode.Point;
```